# Populate HBox with buttons each clickable different depending on ResultSet from Database

Tags: java, javafx

I have database with job candidates. On main page i should display some informations and on name clicked should open another window with more informations, but when name clicked i get error. I tried putting names in labels firs but as label is not clickable i switched to button. My code was working until i added `setOnAction` so i suppose that is problem here

**My question is** : Is there a way to create unspecified number of buttons each sending different id to method in while loop

Here is my code:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id,ime,prezime,glavna_tehnologija,znanje from kandidat ");

while (rs.next()) {
HBox hBox = new HBox(40);

Button btn = new Button(rs.getString("ime") + " " + rs.getString("prezime"));

btn.setOnAction(e->{           
try {
new PrikazInformacijaKandidataProzor().pregled(rs.getInt("id"));
} catch (SQLException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

});

hBox.getChildren().addAll(new Label(Integer.toString(rs.getInt("id"))),btn, new Label(rs.getString("glavna_tehnologija")), new Label(rs.getString("znanje")));
    kandidatiV.getChildren().add(hBox);
        }
```

My `PrikazInformacijaKandidataProzor()` has method `pregled(int id)` that is supposed to take id of candidate and based on that display from database informations but when i click on any name that is displayed in button i get error

```
Dec 06, 2018 4:01:46 PM gui.Main lambda$start$0
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:790)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2473)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2568)
    at gui.Main.lambda$start$0(Main.java:111)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your Button’s action handler is called *later,* when the user presses the button.  The ResultSet is no longer valid when that happens.  Call `rs.getInt` *before* your call to `btn.setOnAction`.